# Hiding products based on customer tag Shopify search.liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I hope someone may be able to help with this.

I am currently setting up my store with shopify and have duplicated my products for retail and wholesale customers.

The only issue I am faced with is that the retail products are still showing when a customer with the 'wholesale' tag uses the search box.

I was wondering if I add a 'retail' tag to the relevant products, can add any code in search.liquid so that if the customer.tag contains 'wholesale' do not show products with product.tags 'retail' or something along those lines?

My current search.liquid looks like:

```
<!-- /templates/search.liquid -->
{% comment %}
```

To return only products or pages in results:
    - http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/return-only-product-in-storefront-search-results
    - Or manually add type=product or type=page to the search URL as a parameter

```
{% endcomment %}

{% comment %}
  Check to enforce respond.js
{% endcomment %}
{% assign respond_js_secret_key = shop.domain | md5 %}
{% unless search.terms == respond_js_secret_key %}

{% comment %}
  Avoid accessing search.results before the opening paginate tag.
  If you do, the pagination of results will be broken.
{% endcomment %}
{% paginate search.results by 12 %}

  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid__item">
      <header class="section-header text-center">
        {% if search.performed %}
          {% if search.results_count == 0 %}
            <h1 class="text-center">{{ 'general.search.no_results_html' | t: terms: search.terms }}</h1>
          {% else %}
            <h1 class="text-center">{{ 'general.search.results_for_html' | t: terms: search.terms }}</h1>
          {% endif %}
        {% else %}
          <h1 class="text-center">{{ 'general.search.title' | t }}</h1>
        {% endif %}
        <hr class="hr--small">
      </header>

      {% include 'search-bar', search_btn_style: 'btn', search_bar_location: 'search-bar--page' %}

      {% if search.performed %}

        <hr class="hr--medium hr--clear">

        <div class="grid-uniform">

          {% for item in search.results %}
{% assign itemIswholesale = false %}
{% if item.tags contains 'wholesale' or item.title contains 'wholesale' %}
{% assign itemIswholesale = true %}
{% endif %}

{% if itemIswholesale and customer and customer.tags contains 'wholesale' %}
{% if item.object_type == 'product' %}
{% assign product = item %}
{% include 'product-grid-item' %}
{% else %}
<div>
<div>
<a href="{{ item.url }}">
<span>
<span>{{ item.title }}</span>
{{ item.content | strip_html | truncatewords: 60 }}
</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% else %}
{% unless itemIswholesale %} 
{% if item.object_type == 'product' %}
{% assign product = item %}
{% include 'product-grid-item' %}
{% else %}
<div>
<div>
<a href="{{ item.url }}">
<span>
<span>{{ item.title }}</span>
{{ item.content | strip_html | truncatewords: 60 }}
</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endunless %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
        </div>

        {% if paginate.pages > 1 %}
          {% include 'pagination' %}
        {% endif %}

      {% endif %}

    </div>
  </div>

{% endpaginate %}

{% else %}
  {% include 'respond' %}
  {% layout none %}
{% endunless %}
```

I am a complete novice and have managed to get by this far following help and tutorials online so any help would be very much appreciated.

I can't afford to subscribe to an additional app at present, such as locksmith and would really like to keep control so I can continue administration in future,

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You may try doing something like that  inside the
   {% if search.performed %} 
condition.

First get some information about user and store it:

```
{% assign wholesale = false %}
{% if customer %}
  {% assign customer_tags = customer.tags | split: "," %}
  {% if customer_tags contains 'wholesale' %}
    {% assign wholesale = true %}
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Explanations : first you assign a false statement to the wholesale status. Then you check if it is customer ( no need to go further if user is not connected). If he is, then you check if he has a wholesale tag. If he is you assign a true statement.

Then you are able to display something different this way:

```
{% for result in search.results %}
  {% if wholesale %}
    Do something
  {% else %}
    Do something else
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Please not that you may have some issues with pagination.